# Looking for the existence of an ENV Variable

Tags: bash, windows-subsystem-for-linux

So, I'm guessing this may be a bug, or maybe I've botched something up, I dunno...

I have a script that was always working but I've been tasked to make it work using the new WSL2. I've snipped out the first block of code as it's giving me issues right off the bat. As you'll see below, I'm simply trying to determine if a variable has been set or not. This works in my Linux VM and also in Cygwin, however, it doesn't work in WSL2. Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $test_var
set -e

if [ ! -d "$test_var" ]; then
    echo Please set test_var.
    exit
fi
```

When I run this in any of the working systems I get the output of the variable.

In WSL2 I get the output of the variable followed by Please set test_var. And it stops the script due to the set -e as it's supposed to do thinking the var isn't set.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: `-d` tests if test_var is a directory...

Comment: why are you testing if the variable is a directory? why not test it isn't empty? `if [ -z "$test_var" ]`

Comment: Note that if you test for a directory (-d), the directory has to **exist** as a subdirectory **in the directory where this script is run**.

Comment: To clarify my last comment: your script basically test if a directory exists. If the directory does not exist, then your script prints the message, and exits.  That message doesn't make much sense as is; it should be something like "could not find directory $test_var".

Comment: On the other hand, if you intend to just see if some env.var (no matter what it represents) exists, then use `-z`. But in that case, I can't 'place' the negation, I can't square it with the message. You should then just use `if [ -z "$test_var" ]`.

Answer (score 0):

If your intention is to check if a directory exists (whose name apparently needs to be set as an environment variable in $test_var), if that directory exists **relative to the current directory where the script is executed**, you want something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$test_var"
set -e

if [ ! -d "$test_var" ]; then
    echo "cannot find directory $test_var"
    exit
fi
```

Note that here I have only changed your message, and your problem might possibly be explained by the fact that you do not have such a directory under WSL2.

If, on the other hand, you want to check if some environment variable (whatever it represents) is set, you want the `-z` option, something like:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "$test_var"
set -e

if [ -z "$test_var" ]; then
    echo "Please set test_var."
    exit
fi
```

Note the absence of your negation sign (`!`).

Comment: Thanks Roadowl for the quick response, but that opens more questions. As I indicated above, this works in every other environment I've tried it in besides WSL2. $test_var is a directory. It sit's at C:\testVar. In cygwin that path would be something like /cygdrive/c/testVar.....in WSL2 that path would be /mnt/c/testVar. It matters not where I run it from.

Comment: Those paths are absolute, and indeed not really relative to the directory you run the script in...

Comment: ... Anyway, before I continue this comment -- did you mean to type `/mnt/c/$testVar` in your last comment, or is it really literally `/mnt/c/testVar`?

Comment: If the latter, you should do `export test_var=/mnt/c/testVar` somewhere in your $HOME/.bashrc, or run your script like so: `test_var=/mnt/c/testVar myscript`.

Comment: And, of course, you must make sure the directory `/mnt/c/testVar` actually does exist.